# How to select a set of contiguous images in the stock Gallery app?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, gallery, images

I am running Android 4.4 KitKat on a Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo.

I would like to know whether there is a way to select to select a set of contiguous images in the stock Gallery app. I took a lot of pictures in a flower shop with each pic displaying each flower together with its name, and there are now about 120 pics altogether. I need to select a contiguous set of pictures (by somehow selecting only the first and last pics in the whole range to select the whole range, and move the selected pics to a separate album.

How can I accomplish this on my Android phone?

Comment: if you are ready to accept anything except stock Gallery app then you must check QuickPic   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder